# is a checkbox vulnerable to sql injection?

Tags: c#

I'm developing an application in c# that has some checkboxes. Basically, a list of users is on the screen and a check box by each user name is used to indicate whether an action is to be done for that user.

```
protected void btnMoveToAssigned_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> idsToAssign = new List<int>();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvUnassigned.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox checkbox = row.FindControl("cbToAssign") as CheckBox;
                if (checkbox.Checked)
                {
                    int id;
                    if (Int32.TryParse(gvUnassigned.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out id))
                    {
                        idsToAssign.Add(id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I build a list of userIds, which is passed to this method:

```
  public static bool AddApplicationCommandUsers(ORMPortalDataContext dc, ApplicationCommand applicationCOmmand, List<int> userIds)
    {
        List<security_command_xref_Linq> userApplicationCommandList = new List<security_command_xref_Linq>();

        foreach (int userId in userIds)
        {
            security_command_xref_Linq scxL = new security_command_xref_Linq();
            scxL.userID = userId;
            scxL.command = applicationCOmmand.CommandAbbr;
           // scxL.Creator = ApplicationUser.GetCurrentUser().Id;
           // scxL.Created = DateTime.Now;

            userApplicationCommandList.Add(scxL);
        }

        dc.security_command_xref_Linqs.InsertAllOnSubmit(userApplicationCommandList);

        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
```

I had it scanned by the Burp Suite and it gave me these results:

> The
>   ctl00%24MainContent%24ctrlManageCommandUsers%24ctrlApplicationCommandUsersAssignment%24gvUnassigned%24ctl32%24cbToAssign
>   parameter appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. The
>   payload ,(select * from (select(sleep(20)))a) was submitted in the
>   ctl00%24MainContent%24ctrlManageCommandUsers%24ctrlApplicationCommandUsersAssignment%24gvUnassigned%24ctl32%24cbToAssign
>   parameter. The application took more than 22062 milliseconds to
>   respond to the request, compared with 62 milliseconds for the original
>   request, indicating that the injected SQL command caused a time delay.

I don't see how the cbToAssign could be vulnerable. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Well, if you just use a checkbox for just true or false, then it is no problem, if you need to get some kind value from the checkbox, like an id or something, I recommend using a different approach.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET CheckBox?  _Any_ values coming from the client are potentially vulnerable.  Granted, fiddling the value of a CheckBox and manipulating the viewstate to be correct would be extremely tricky, but it's still a potential route for attack.

Comment: Read the result message carefully. It explains it all, but could also be a false positive.

Comment: yes, it is an ASP.NET checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rogue client may just be sending a POST request, and not actually using a normal web browser to send malicious data; Therefore the value *could* be susceptible to attack, especially if you just use the value as is to build a SQL string.

Comment: >especially if you just use the value as is to build a SQL string.< that's part of what has me scratching my head over this...We're using LINQ, so I don't see how a SQL injection  would work. I'm not building a SQL string with it. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the report is from that exact code path? Have you checked the value isn't used by other callbacks?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. I checked for instances of cbToAssign and there were few. thanks.